# Ajax gives me this error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

this is my ajax script and this is the error Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression the code works and removes the second drop down menu but doesn't append the updated 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Channel_dropdown').change(function(){
        var channel = $('#Channel_dropdown').val()
        alert(channel);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/advanced_subchannel/",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'ch_id' : channel,
            },
            success:function(req){
                $('#subChannel_dropdown').remove();
                $(req).find('#advancedsearch_subchannels').each(function(i){
                    $('#advancedsearch_subchannels').append($(req).find('#subChannel_dropdown'));
                });
            }   
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: 1. If you are using ie, remove the `,` after `channel`. 
2. what does `alert(req)` return ?
3. Change `$(req)` in `.append($(req).find` to `append($(this).find`

Comment: alert req returns this :

Comment: escape it within ``, or just edit the question and post it there.

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <title></title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: @karthikr it has another part but i couldnt post it because of the charackter limit anyway i did change $(req) in .append($(req).find to append($(this).find and it ddnt work

Comment: thats fine.. The logic within success is what i feel the error is.. Just figure out if that is what you really want to do

Comment: @karthikr i am new to ajax but what i have found out is that i have a problem in  the loop statment and the append statment those are not working

Comment: why do you have `function(i)` - `function()` should be enough

Comment: the problem is that when i inspect element i find the subchannel added in the code in the console but why is'nt it showed on the page

Comment: is there a css - like `display: none` or something?

Comment: no there is not any css that has display none

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple small things "wrong" with the syntax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Channel_dropdown').change(function () {
        var channel = $('#Channel_dropdown').val(); //Forgot semicolon
        alert(channel);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/advanced_subchannel/",
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                'ch_id': channel //Extra unneeded comma
            },
            success: function (req) {
                $('#subChannel_dropdown').remove();
                $(req).find('#advancedsearch_subchannels').each(function (i) {
                    $('#advancedsearch_subchannels').append($(req).find('#subChannel_dropdown'));
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

There are sites that validate javascript for you, check out http://jsfiddle.net/ they have a built in validator that uses http://www.jslint.com/